# start a service with popen : command not stopping

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I try to make a backup script in python and start, stop a service with popen...
Stopping the service is working, but unfortunatly starting the service works, but blocks the rest of the execution, the scripts stays there, why ?

**Seems to be somehow linked with the httpd service... :-(**

the program config element is like "service;httpd;start" or "/etc/init.d/myprog;start"

```
class execute(actions):
    def __init__(self,config,section,logger):
        self.name="execute"
        actions.__init__(self,config,section,logger)

    def process(self):
        try:
            program=self.config.get(self.section,"program").split(";")
            self.logger.debug("program=%s" % program)
            p = subprocess.Popen(program, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

            if stdout:
                self.logger.info(stdout)
            if stderr:
                self.logger.error(stderr)

            return p.returncode

        except Exception:
            self.logger.exception(Exception)
```

Comment: Hmm, what happens when you type `service myprog start` in command line? Would you have to wait until you type `service myprog stop` in another terminal?

Comment: no that goes pretty quick, about 5 secs

Comment: I'm also wondering why stdout is only shown when command ends... I don't see it while running

Answer (score 2):

You have to open a stdin as a pipe as well, and then close it (if you use read() and write() instead of communicate()).

```
p = subprocess.Popen(..., stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.close()
print "Stdout:", p.stdout.read()
print "Stderr:", p.stderr.read()
```

If it doesn't work, and you don't really need any checks, just close all pipes after call to Popen, what will cause program execution and detachment 
from pipes.

Warning: This will make program run as a daemon if it doesn't terminate on its own.

After doing this you may call wait() to see whether it'll block as well. And use exitcodes to check for eventual errors.

There are not much of them. Just service started or not. Sometimes even it returns that service is running, but service crashes.

To check whether service script is still running, but without blocking, use:

```
if p.poll()==None: print "Still running"
```

Else, poll() returns the exit code.

This works neatly for starting and stopping a service:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
service = "brltty"
p = Popen(["service", service, "start"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
# Note: using sequence uses shell=0
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print "Stdout:", stdout
print "Stderr:", stderr
```

Don't forget to change start to stop :D :D :D

Comment: In Fact I'm trying to stop and start and normal linux service...
Starting needs about 30 seconds, stopping about 15...

But the scripts doesn't finish even after 10 Minutes, when everything is already running again since a while...

If I running without pipes, I didn't know if the command went well, or if there was an erro

Comment: Yes, I saw what you tried. Don't use communicate() if you really have to dig through pipes. Use p.stdout.read() or p.stderr.read(). And as I said, you wouldn't be able to deduce much, and even won't receive any errors regardless they're there. The extra problem is that the service script starts the service as well. So it is the script that calls a daemon. Sometimes it may confuse things. Do what I say, it works!

Comment: Sorry, closing stdin before communicate() causes an IO error. I forgot. But stopping works without closing anything, with communicate but when stdin is opened as a PIPE as well.

Comment: What's the difference between you last peace of code and mine ? I'm not sure to understand ?

Comment: That it has stdin=PIPE. As I wrote in first line of the answer. That causes communicate() to close the stdin after calling it. That in turn ensures that the program is terminated. Without it, it seems, service script for some reason blocks. This works for me, does it work in your case?

Comment: I've added your code and just use it twice, but the start doesn't work... 

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
service = "myprog"
print 'first popen'
p = Popen(["service", service, "stop"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
# Note: using sequence uses shell=0
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print "Stdout:", stdout
print "Stderr:", stderr

print "second popen"
p = Popen(["service", service, "start"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
# Note: using sequence uses shell=0
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print "Stdout:", stdout
print "Stderr:", stderr

Comment: Doesn't work in which sense? Simply nothing happends? Maybe it's a too short time between two Popen's. Put some sleep in betveen or do while p.poll()==None: sleep(0.001); This will wait for first Popen() to finish any work done after EOF is sent. Although after communicate() the called program should be closed. Does this work independently, I mean, when you call one for start then other for stop?

Comment: I've just found out, it is linked with httpd... doing a serivce start httpd doesn't work, whereas it works fine with cron and other services... Any Idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `p.communicate()` waits for the process to terminate.

Refer to: [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
>   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. **Wait for process to terminate**.
>   The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child
>   process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

You can try to use [`p.poll()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) instead. This method doesn't wait for a process to terminate.

Comment: I still don't undestand why service myprog stop is working, and service myprog start not ?
Why is the process not terminating ?

Comment: I'm missing actual commands which are invoked upon start/stop. My guess is that stop terminates the services and returns immediately, thus you are not observing waiting on `p.communicate` in this case. However service start invokes a long running activity and `p.communicate` waits for this activity to complete.

Comment: No thats my problem the "service xxx start" process is during about a few seconds, but p.communicate stays stucked...  I don't explain me why